# window.innerWidth/Height not updated in resize handler in WKWebView

Tags: ios, safari, wkwebview

I have some fullscreen web content that I update when the window changes size using the resize event.

```
window.onresize = function()
{
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;
    ...
}
```

This works fine in the Safari app but it is not working in a `WKWebView`. It is giving me the wrong window dimensions when the device changes screen orientations on both iPhone and iPad in a `WKWebView`.

Specifically for iPad I am showing the web view in a navigation controller. When I switch to portrait mode I get (768x768) dimensions instead of (768x960) which are the correct dimensions.

Is there a workaround to this issue?

Answer (score 4):

It seems like `window.clientWidth` / `window.clientHeight` don't get updated before the resize event fires.

I found two solutions to the issue:

- use `document.documentElement.clientWidth` instead of `window.innerWidth`
- listen to the `orientationchange` event instead of the `resize` event (`window.clientWidth` seems to be already updated at this point)

Comment: document.documentElement.clientHeight was no better as of Mar 18 2021 on an iPad running IOS 14.4.1