# WKWebView: window.innerWidth reporting wrong value

Tags: wkwebview

I'm hosting some 3rd-party content in a WKWebView, and their content doesn't resize correctly on orientation change. It does resize correctly in Safari though.

```js
window.onresize = function() { console.log(window.innerWidth) }
```

This prints the *same* width every time (768), regardless of orientation, but when I evaluate `window.innerWidth` on the console after the rotation has completed, it prints the correct width.

Is this a known issue? Are there any workarounds?

UPDATE:

What I ended up doing is re-firing the `resize` event after a delay. It's ugly but it solves my use case.

```swift
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: nil) { _ in
        // Orientation change triggers the `resize` event, but `window.innerWidth` is
        // wrong *during that time*. By calling resize a second time, we let content resize itself
        // according to the correct dimensions.             
        // There's more! Sometimes the dimensions are still wrong after the rotation has completed,
        // so we have to wait. The minimum reliable delay varies widely across devices.
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(750)) {
            self.webView?.evaluateJavaScript("window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));", completionHandler: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I had the same issue. You should use document.body.offsetWidth instead of window.innerWidth, because window.innerWidth can take additional 500ms until it updates itself after the window resize event. This is true at least for WKWebView in iOS.

Comment: Good to know, but I'm hosting third-party content, so I can't change their code.

Comment: document.body.offsetWidth is always 0 for me. document.documentElement.clientWidth seems to be correct though. also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/43302314/176140